# the covariance matrix returned by function ‘numpy.polyfit’

Tags: numpy

when I set ‘cov=True’，the function ‘numpy.polyfit’ will return a covariance matrix，I wonder what does it mean and how to calculate it，Thanks a lot ！！！

the author of ‘ZSSR’ super resolution algorithm adopted a learning rate adjustment strategy，which first take a linear fit of reconstruction error，and then compare the standard deviation and the slope to guide the adjustment of learning rate。I can‘t see the relationship between the learning rate and the standard deviation（in fact I don’t know what does the covariance matrix returned by the funciton mean），so I wonder know the detail of this covariance matrix。